# "You must be logged in to access this page" error

Tags: php, authentication

I have my `login.php` set up so that whenever a login is successful, it automatically directs to `profile.php`. However, even if the login *is* successful, whenever I go to `profile.php` it still says "You must be logged in to access this page". Why?

Here's my `login.php`:

```
$email = $_POST['email-field'];
$password = $_POST['password-field'];

if ($email && $password)
{
    $connect = mysql_connect("xx", "xx", "xx") or die("Couldnt connect!");
    mysql_select_db(xx) or die("Couldnt find db");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if ($numrows != 0)
    {

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $email = $row['email'];
            $md5password = $row['password'];
        }

        if ($email == $email && $md5password == md5($password))
        {
            header("Location: profile.php");
            $_SESSION['email']==$email;
        }
        else
            echo "Incorrect password";
    }
    else
        die("That user doessnt exist!");
}
else
    die("Please enter a username and a password");
```

And my `profile.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<?php 

include('get-info.php');

session_start();

if ($_SESSION['email'])
    echo "<a href=logout.php>Logout</a>";
else
    die("You must be logged in to access this page");


?>


<html>

    <head>

        <title>

            R-A | Profile

        </title>

        <link href='css.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

    </head>

    <body class='body3' >

        <div class='logo-bar'>

            <div class='menu'>

                <img src='images/rateaway.png' class='logo-bar-img' />

                    <div class='menu-options'>

                        <a href='index.php' class='menu-links' >Home</a>

                        <a href='profile.php' class='menu-links' >Profile</a>

                        <a href='profile.php' class='menu-links' >Friends</a>

                    </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class='profile-main-content' >

            <div class='profile-current-info'>

                <p class='profile-name'> <?php get_info('iran_mateu@yahoo.com', 'name'); ?> </p>

                <img src='<?php get_info('iran_mateu@yahoo.com', 'profilepic'); ?>' class='profile-pic'/>

                <p class='profile-dob' > Born: <?php get_info('iran_mateu@yahoo.com', 'dob'); ?> </p>

                <p class='profile-country' > Currently lives in: <?php get_info('iran_mateu@yahoo.com', 'country'); ?> </p>

                <p class='profile-gender' > Gender: <?php get_info('iran_mateu@yahoo.com', 'gender'); ?> </p>

            </div>

            <div class='profile-edit-info' >



            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: Careful about SQL injection on your `email-field`. Use `mysql_real_escape_string` to escape your string, or better yet, prepared statements and drop the `mysql_` methods altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not writing to the session after a successful login. Consider this part:

```
if ($email==$email&&$md5password==md5($password))
    {
        header("Location: profile.php");
        $_SESSION['email']==$email;
    }
```

You should be using `=` instead of `==`. Since you are not, you are **not** assigning `$email` to `$_SESSION['email']`. You're not assigning anything, just doing a comparison (and discarding its return value). So it should be:

```
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
```

Also, you should add `session_start();` to the top of login.php, as minitech suggested on his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to start a session. On each page you want to use sessions, you must call:

```
session_start();
```

Also make sure you do this before outputting any content, or it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition unless you have a solid validation to not allow multiple emails into your db on your sign up page your query should be:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' LIMIT 1");
```

This will make sure only one record is retrieved (which in theory should always be the case) - but if more than one did manage to get retrieved, it would break your code.

Lastly  ($email == $email... hmm not sure you got this right as this will always be true as you're essentially just checking that it equals itself (which it always will be), I think you got confused becuase you actually have overwritten your $email variable that you got from the $_POST with your data from the db. So you should amend your code to:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
   $db_email = $row['email'];
   $md5password = $row['password'];
}

if ( $email == $db_email && $md5password == md5($password) )
{
   // assign variables / do things BEFORE redirecting as there is a risk that
   // your session data may not get written in some circumstances
   $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
   header("Location: profile.php");
   // always good habit to make sure nothing else is done after the redirection
   die();
}
```

**EDIT:**

One more tip:

**This:**

```
$email = $_POST['email-field'];
$password = $_POST['password-field'];

if ($email && $password)
{
```

**Would be better as:**

```
session_start();
if ( isset($_POST['email-field']) && isset($_POST['email-field']) )
{
    $email = $_POST['email-field'];
    $password = $_POST['password-field'];
    // add some validation to your $email and $password variables
```

The above will help avoid notices if your $_POST variables are not actually set as in your original code you were using the $_POST variables as if they had been set (which they may not have been) - again just good practice.

Answer (score 0):

This function note required,

> if ($email==$email&&$md5password==md5($password))
>       {
>           header("Location: profile.php");
>           $_SESSION['email']==$email;
>       }

By: [Gaya Rambut](http://modelgayarambutterbaru.blogspot.com/)